# How to use multiprocessing pools inside a for loop python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am new here but I wanted to ask something regarding multiprocessing.

So I have some huge raster tiles that I process and extract information and I found that delivering tons of pickle files is faster than appending to a dataframe. The point is that I loop over each of my tiles for processing and I create pools inside a for loop

```
#This creates a directory for my pickle files
if not os.path.exists('pkl_tmp'):
    os.mkdir('pkl_tmp')
```

Here I start looping over each one of my tiles and create a pool with the grid cells that I want to process, then I use the map function to apply all my nasty processing to each cell of my grid.

```
for GHSL_tile in ROI.iloc[4:].itertuples():
    ct += 1
    L18_cells = GHSL_query(GHSL_tile, L18_grid)
    vector_tile = poligonize_tile(GHSL_tile)

    print(datetime.today())
    subdir = './pkl_tmp/{}/'.format(ct)
    if not os.path.exists(subdir):
        os.mkdir(subdir)

    if vector_tile is not None:  

        # assign how many cores will be used
        num_processes = int(multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 15)
        chunk_size = 1  # chunk size set to 1 to return cell like outputs

        # break the dataframe as a list
        chunks = [L18_cells.iloc[i:i + chunk_size, :] for i in range(0, L18_cells.shape[0], chunk_size)]
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processes)

        result = pool.map(process_cell, chunks)

        del result

    else:
        print('Tile # {} skipped'.format(ct))


print('GHSL database created')
```

In fact this has not errors, it takes around 2 days executing due to the size of my data and sometimes I had many iddle cores (specially towards the end of a tile).

My question is:
**I tried using `map_async` instead of map and it was creating files really fast, even sometimes processes multiple tiles at the same time which is wonderful, the problem is that when it creates the directory for my last tile, the code gets out of the for loop and many tasks end up not being executed. What am I doing wrong? How can I make the `map_async` function work better or how can I avoid iddle cores (slow down) when I use the `map` function?**

Thank you in advance

PC resources is definitely not a problem

Comment: First things first, why you create the pool inside the loop, it should be outside of it. You only need one pool. Second, my guess is that map is blocking. I cant really remember but I think that you need to join map_async calls or use a callback to when they are completed, you need to be carefull where you put this otherwise it will serialize things again, my guess is that you should accumulate and join all then togethter in the end of the script

Comment: There is a pool.join() too, I dont know if it would help in this case

Comment: Alright, but each pool that I create takes a different vector tile argument, that is why I have it on a for loop, how can I fix this?

Comment: You mean `chunks`, you create the pool outside the loop and call `pool.map` inside loop

Comment: Not only the chunks are different, the variable ``` vector_tile``` changes for each loop iteration, I have it as a global variable so the list only takes one argument for the function

Comment: The pool creation dont depend on these `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processes)`. The idea of pool is having a single pool where you can drag jobs, it make no sense to have more than one pool. Google for thread pools, is the same concepts but we're using processes instead of threads